# How to remove dulipate object from list

Tags: java, arraylist

I was asked in interview to remove duplicate student objects from list, where student object may contains different properties , condition is I should not use either set or hashmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sort the list.
2. Iterate through the list, checking to see if the current object is equal to its neighbor.

This requires O(n*log(n)) to sort the list and O(n) to iterate through the sorted list.

Thus, the total runtime complexity is O(n*log(n)) + O(n) = **O(n*log(n))**.

Comment: But how to remove duplicate in that way

Comment: You can remove the elements as you iterate through the list (you need to be careful in how you implement this, so that you don't accidentally skip over any elements). If a certain element is equal to its neighbor, then remove it and continue. If no equal neighbors are found, then each element in the list must be unique.

Comment: is that any other way  to this better , is this only technique

Comment: You could do it with a hashtable in **O(n)** time, but this would go against the requirements of your post.

Comment: Upon interview, you're supposed to bring up the vague requirements. In this case, the definition of object equality and less/greater than is not clear. Perhaps the object has a field with an int value. Thus value comparison is easy. With that info, you can create a function for the comparison. And then, you can sort the list to remove duplicates. You can not sort any list without knowing the definition of object equality. Is that clear?

Answer (score 1):

Sort the ArrayList and loop through. But how do you define duplicate object? Equal reference or have the same properties?

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by comparing the reference of student objects.

Answer (score 0):

In List there is no direct method to remove duplicate. The fastest way to remove duplicate is Sets. In list to remove duplicate you will have to override hashcode() and equals() method and then will have to iterate whole list for one object.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your interviewer trying to get "java.util.Set" as answer from you which will not allow duplicate objects.  This is typical standard question you can expect.